# How to store keyboard keys being pressed using pynput?

Tags: python, dictionary, pynput, keylogger

I'm currently working on a keylogger type python script and I'm having issues storing which keys at any given moment is held down.

I've written this small piece of code to demonstrate my problem:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import time

def on_press(key):
    print(f'{key} pressed')
    
    if not key in keys_down:
        keys_down[key] = time.time()
    
    print(keys_down)

def on_release(key):
    print(f'{key} release')

    del keys_down[key]

    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

keys_down = dict()

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I want to store which keyboard-keys are currently being pressed in the dictionary `keys_down`.

 I also want to know when a certain keyboard-key first started being pressed.

 Therefore my dictionary's key-value pairs are stored as follows:

```
keys_down = {
    keyboard key 1: timestamp when first pressed
    keyboard key 2: timestamp when first pressed
    ...
}
```

When a keyboard-key is released I delete the key-value pair with the key equivalent to the released keyboard-key.

I hope that sentence made sense.

The problem arises when using a `crtl`-shortcut to rapidly.

Sometimes the keyboard-key outputted when pressed is not the same keyboard-key outputted when released. Because of this, the `del`-function throws an error hence it's trying to delete a key-value par that does not exist.


I really hope you can help me get around this problem.
Have a great day :)

Comment: What about just catching the `KeyError ` exception from the failed `del` operation using a `try/except` block?

Comment: Yeah but then I will have leftovers in the keys_down dict. When a key is released it will not be removed from the dict

Answer (score 1):

It's not a satisfying answer, but the code works when installing an older version of pynput (1.4). In this version, keys aren't stored as strange hex values but instead the literal keys being pressed